# How do I load Angular code behind routes modularly?

Tags: angularjs

I want to organize my angular code like this:

```
project/
  thing/
    thing.js
    view.html
  other_thing/
    other_thing.js
    view.html
```

Then I want to include routing that picks the thing based on url params:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/thing', {
    templateUrl: 'thing/thing.html',
    controller: 'thingController'
  })
  .when('/other_thing', {
    templateUrl: 'other_thing/other_thing.html',
    controller: 'otherThingController'
  });

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

What I'm missing is how to load `thingController` and `otherThingController` on demand. If I've got 50 different controllers I don't want to load all of them up front, I want to wait until the client actually visits the route to load the js, similar to how the templateUrl isn't loaded until the user navigates there.

Comment: there are multiple ways to do lazy loading, from webpack and systemjs configurations to libraries like ocLazyLoad.

Comment: @Claries ocLaxyLoad and angularAMD used for lazy loading, he need this thing on url.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you

1. [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/)
2. [angularAMD](http://marcoslin.github.io/angularAMD/#/home)